# Multiple APIs v One API

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, enterprise-architecture

Is it normal to have a bounded context spread accross multiple APIs or should there really be one API per bounded context?

I am trying to understand if I can use the Scatter Gatherer pattern (https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/BroadcastAggregate.html) in a hobby application I am developing to improve my knowledge of DDD.

**Multiple APIs - Use scatter gatherer**

The example I have posted is for a mortgage application where a quote request is broadcasted to multiple vendors and then once a suitable amount of quotes is received then the aggregator chooses the best quote.

In this scenario it appears that there is a bounded context spread accross multiple APIs.  The solution structure will look something like this:

The solution structure will look something like this:

```
Offers.API //Contains the aggregator
Offer1.API
Offer2.API
Offer3.API
```

The domain model in the Offers.API will look something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
   public string Name {get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set; }
   public List<Offer> Offers {get; set; }

   public void AssignOffer(Offer offer)
   {
    Offers.Add(offer);
   }
}
```

The Offers are passed to the AssignOffer by the aggregator.  The Offer class will be anemic in the Offers.API because the domain logic is contained in the other APIs.

I believe the benefit of this approach is that it is more configurable.  Every time a new offer is added then a new API can be created.

**Single API**

Instead I could just have one API and map offers from the database to classes using Table Per Hierarchy mappings.  Every new offer added will require the application to be compiled and published.

Comment: I would think you want runtime configurable for adding/removing external vendors.

Comment: @Erik Eidt, runtime configurable means multiple api's.  Is that right? Thanks.

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: @Erik Eidt, would you expect to see this for a single bounded context? If you could post an answer then that would be great else a comment would be good.

Comment: @w0051977, Are your vendors hosting the APIs, or are they included through another mechanism?  The main idea behind a federated search is that you can add new vendors just by updating a configuration.

Comment: @Berin Loritsch, it is more of a learning exercise, however I will say: yes.  Is there any problem distributing domain logic across APIs like this? I realise the code will work - I am asking more from an architectural/"best practice" perspective.  Thanks.

Comment: It's ok to split a given domain into smaller domains. It's like SRP. A single responsability might involve different sort of tasks that altogether works as a whole. It's also applies to distributed systems like MS. However, as you may guess, it comes at a price. Complexity.

Comment: @Laiv, is there not a one to one relationship between a bounded context and an API? In fact here the Aggregate domain model to distributed across multiple microservices.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The API is just the domain's public interface. Under the hood, the API can be implemented in many ways. It can be a single service or it can be several services working altogether. There are a root service and several child-services working on the same domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an architectural standpoint, what you are talking about is probably more commonplace than you may realize.  Essentially, there are multiple reasons for having multiple instances of APIs.  In fact, it's kind of what [Microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) are.

Reasons for multiple APIs:

- The APIs are hosted by your providers (in this case mortgage lenders) and you are consuming them
- You need to dynamically scale to handle load for a portion of your application
- You are *sharding* data across multiple nodes (like most NOSQL data stores)
- You are implementing your system using microservices

Your problem is essentially an [aggregated search](https://www.google.com/search?q=aggregated%20search&cad=h) problem.  You make an asynchronous request to multiple providers and when you collect enough results, you start prioritizing and sorting the results.

To answer your question, yes it is normal to have several microservices (small APIs) working together in a solution.  It's a valid design decision, but the flexibility you get from microservices does come at a price.

- Microservices are more complex to develop, test and deploy
- They allow you to spin up additional copies of services to handle demand and then get rid of the excess services when they are no longer needed
- When combined with [Single Page Applications](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/demystifying-single-page-applications-3068d0555d46) (SPA) you can keep track of sessions on the client so you don't have to manage that on the server, reducing the intercommunication needed somewhat

You'll find that most well known applications that handle a large amount of concurrent users are built using a microservice architecture, so it scales well.  However, most of those applications also started out a lot more simply and evolved that way over time.  If this is for your personal learning, I would recommend getting familiar with microservice architecture.  If this is for a real project, I would recommend starting with an approach your team already understands and potentially migrating to microservices if you start getting close to the level of traffic that would mandate that approach.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand the Microservices architecture.  However, I wander if there should be one microservice per bounded context? Is it normal to have a bounded context spread across multiple APIs like this? The Aggregate Roots are also spread across multiple APIs.  +1 for the reference to Aggregate Search.

Comment: @w0051977, like any design, you weigh your options and choose the most appropriate answer.  DDD is a way to design your system from a logical perspective.  How you draw your boundaries is up to you, but having multiple copies of a microservice in your system is fine.  If a different configuration makes them _logically_ different, that fits your bounded context model.  When talking about design, don't confuse the logical services with service instances.  There are runtime and deployment reasons for having multiple instances of any given service.

Comment: the other concern I have is that the Offer class in the Offers.API will be anemic because all the domain logic for Offers is distributed across the APIs.  Does that make sense? Does that make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: @w0051977, wouldn't that central Offers API be your Offers Aggregator?  The domain logic for each provider will be unique to that provider.  The only thing left is to aggregate and decide which offers to present.  That may not be as anemic as you are thinking over time.  Particularly if you incorporate some machine learning to suggest the best match for the user.

Comment: Could you explain how machine learning could be applied here? As stated it is more of a learning application.

Comment: ML is a bit out of scope for this answer, and I am by no means an expert on the subject.  However, intelligently picking the best match to the user's needs is an algorithm that would be applied in your aggregator.  You can do a manual best matching algorithm to start with which may be very simplistic.  Unfortunately, you'll have to do your own research on ML for how to apply selection criteria.  I know just enough to know when I need an expert help.

Comment: One more question before I accept.  Where would I call the scatterer from - the command that uses the Offers; the application service, which calls the command or somewhere else? I have not used this pattern before.  Thanks again.

Comment: @w0051977, Typically the code that accepts the user input with all the important information that the providers use to present their offerings would initiate that call.  Depending on the load and number of services you would call, it might make sense to simply pop a message on a queue, and have a service that monitors that queue initiate the call to the external APIs.  From a technical standpoint it might help simplify your design if the aggregator also initiates the requests so that you can track if you've received answers from all of your providers or not.  In short, you do have options.

Comment: yes it will be added to RabbitMQ.  However, I am wandering id it should be the application service or command that adds it to the queue.  The application service calls the command.

Comment: Both can work, I don't have any particular opinion on that.  As long as the choice you make has a defensible reason and fits in your vision for the architecture, it should be fine.

Comment: Before I accept - can you think of any domain logic that could be contained in: offers.API.Offer? This is a learning application.  Thanks again.